# Manipulator arm Gazebo

Tags: ros, manipulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I want to simulate a manipulator arm on a mobile robot (URDF) in Gazebo. What package I must use? I saw that the arm_navigation package is used in RVIZ. Can I use this package in Gazebo? Could anyone suggest my another package or mode to simulate a manipulator arm in Gazebo?

Thanks very much and sorry for my English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12501/manipulator-arm-gazebo/) by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could look at the [shadow_robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/shadow_robot). This is a manipulator called the Shadow Hand. It provides a good example of a manipulator in Gazebo. Try [this](http://www.grep-ros.net/ros/ros-start-sr_hand/) tutorial.

You could also try [cob_arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_arm_navigation/Tutorials/Using%20cob_arm_navigation%20to%20plan%20collision-free%20arm%20movements%20for%20Care-O-bot%203).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2012-01-29**:
Thanks for your answer, I'll look at them. Thanks!

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2012-02-13**:
Hi! Finally I have done that with pr2_mechanism (pr2_controller_manager, ...), adding controllers to the joints and my arm is working very well. Thanks for your help.